# How can I count the number of elements within a range in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of elements in a row that fall within a range and then print a new column with the results. After looking around I came up with the following solution, however the results are not consistent. Is the solution too simplistic for what I want to accomplish?
I have the following DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

def val_1(row):
    val_1 = 0
    if row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(1,3):
        val_1 = 3

    elif row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] in range(1,3):
        val_1 = 2
    elif row.loc['A'] in range(1,3):
        val_1 = 1
    return val_1

def val_2(row):
    val_2 = 0
    if row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(3,6) :
        val_2 = 3
    elif row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] in range(3,6) :
        val_2 = 2
    elif row.loc['A'] in range(3,6) :
        val_2 = 1
    return val_2

def val_3(row):
    val_3 = 0
    if row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(6,10) :
        val_3 = 3
    elif row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] in range(6,10) :
        val_3 = 2
    elif row.loc['A']in range(6,10) :
        val_3 = 1
    return val_3

def results():
    df['Val_1'] = df.apply(val_1, axis=1)
    df['Val_2'] = df.apply(val_2, axis=1)
    df['Val_3'] = df.apply(val_3, axis=1)
    print(df)

results()
```

```
   A  B  C  Val_1  Val_2  Val_3
0  9  0  0      0      0      1
1  6  1  0      2      0      1
2  8  5  5      0      3      1
3  9  7  0      0      0      2
4  4  6  2      3      1      2
5  1  5  5      1      3      0
6  8  1  7      2      0      3
7  4  8  5      0      3      2
8  0  6  0      0      0      0
9  3  0  3      0      1      0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is shorter version of your code.
**The problem is in your code:**

- It is checking the range only for last element
- `row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(start,end)`
- Only checking range logic for `C` column (Not for `A` & `B`)

```py
def get_val(row,start,end):
    val = 0
    if row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(start,end) :
        val = 3
    elif row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] in range(start,end) :
        val = 2
    elif row.loc['A'] in range(start,end) :
        val = 1
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df['Val_1'] = df.apply(lambda x:get_val(x,1,3), axis=1)
df['Val_2'] = df.apply(lambda x:get_val(x,3,6), axis=1)
df['Val_3'] = df.apply(lambda x:get_val(x,6,10), axis=1)
```

My Solution

```py
def query_build(start, end):
    query1 = f'A>={start} and A<={end} and B>={start} and B<={end} and C>={start} and C<={end}'
    query2 = f'A>={start} and A<={end} and B>={start} and B<={end}'
    query3 = f'A>={start} and A<={end}'

    return {query1: 3,
            query2: 2,
            query3: 1}

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df['val1'] = 0
df['val2'] = 0
df['val3'] = 0

val_range = {'val1':(1,2),'val2':(3,5),'val3':(6,9)}

for name, r_range in val_range.items():
    query_set = query_build(*r_range)
    for query, val in query_set.items():
        length = len(df.query(query))
        if length:
            df[name][df.query(query).index] = val
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which is using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) (recommended in the Pandas User Guide [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement-conditionally-using-numpy)):

```py
import numpy as np

for n, (start, stop) in enumerate([(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 10)], start=1):
    m = df.isin(range(start, stop))
    condlist = [m.all(axis=1), m[["A", "B"]].all(axis=1), m["A"]]
    df[f"Val_{n}"] = np.select(condlist, [3, 2, 1])
```

- For each iteration build a mask `m` on `df` that checks if the `df` values are in the resp. `range(start, stop)`.
- Based on `m` build a condition list `condlist`: The 1. entry checks if all values are in the range, the 2. checks if the values in columns `A` and `B` are in the range, and the 3. checks if the value in column `A` is in the range - all checks are done *row-wise*.
- Based on `condlist` set the corresponding values from `[3, 2, 1]` (called `choicelist` in the `numpy.select` docs) in the new column, and `0` (standard `default`) if no condition is met.

The selection follows the preferences in you code - see the `numpy.select` documentation:

> When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used.

---

Your question actually sounds a bit different to what you are doing:

> I want to count the number of elements in a row that fall within a range and then print a new column with the results.

If that is your real goal, then you could try something simpler:

```
for n, (start, stop) in enumerate([(1, 3), (3, 6), (6, 10)], start=1):
    df[f"Val_{n}"] = df.isin(range(start, stop)).sum(axis=1)
```

---

Why your approach fails (in addition to @Mazhar's explanation): This

```
if row.loc['A'] and row.loc['B'] and row.loc["C"] in range(1,3):
```

isn't how logical operators like `and` work: You have to fully specify each part of the condition, like:

```
if (row.loc['A'] in range(1,3)) and (row.loc['B'] in range(1,3)) and (row.loc["C"] in range(1,3)):
```

The way you have used it actually resolves to

```
if bool(row.loc['A']) and bool(row.loc['B']) and row.loc["C"] in range(1,3):
```

which here means (since the values are numbers)

```
if (row.loc['A'] != 0) and (row.loc['B'] != 0) and (row.loc["C"] in range(1,3)):
```

Comment: This is an amazing method, but as an answer it may be even better if you explain *why* OPs original approach failed.

Comment: @BeRT2me Yes, you're right. Mazhar already addressed that, so I didn't want repeat it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your educative comments, as you can tell I'm far from being an expert and all your suggestions are highly valued.